# A derivative word search

Tags: knowledge, anagram, word-search

This square is composed of elements, all in the same set, written either horizontally or vertically. There is no overlap, each letter belongs to exactly one word. However, the words are anagrammed. Please find the words, and the specific smallest recognised set which includes these.

```
STREVIES
CEDRRSLM
ALRNELEE
LOAHWANS
AJFEBTMN
PUAYEEUI
LOTVHOMS
MOBOULCE
```

Comment: I'm not going to overdo these, just the one before was quickly solved, and want to see if this lasts longer.

Comment: no it doesn't :P but thanks for composing it!

Comment: Over two legs, Glorfindel 2 : 0 Tom, both matches won before 20 mins.

Comment: Heh, I doubt it would be different if the roles were reversed :)

Comment: Tom, it's [your turn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/97313/11110)

Comment: Glorfindel 2 : 1 Tom. An honourable final result, in which the last match was a scrappy affair on foreign soil, which extended over 50 mins.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They all are

> [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), more specifically [*derived* SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Derived_units) which explains the title, as @oALT notes in the comments

namely

> Coulomb (row 8, starting from column 1)
>  Sievert (row 1, starting from column 2)
>  Joule (column 2, starting from column 2)
>  Lumen (column 7, starting from column 2)
>  Henry (column 4, starting from column 2)
>  Farad (column 3, starting from column 2)
>  Weber (column 5, starting from column 2)
>  Tesla (column 6, starting from column 2)
>  Ohm (row 7, starting from column 1)
>  Volt (row 7, starting from column 4)
>  Pascal (column 1, starting from column 2)
>  Siemens (column 8, starting from row 2)

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen your edit, will delete.

Comment: @hexomino with so many edits, that's completely understandable:)

Comment: doh, I read the 'elements, all in the same set' and was looking for the halogens and so on :P

Comment: (those SI units are also "derived" ones, which explains the title)